# Webservice security check

Tags: c#, web-services, security

I have a website where I am using webservices hosted in a server. Currently anyone can consume my webservices and form a simple request and post/edit stuffs as someone else. I don't want to make a check at each service (which is a big task as I have hundreds of webservices in which I will have to make the changes) to see if the actor using the service and the actordata being sent is the same or not. Is there some way out to make this security check?

Comment: What kind of web services? WCF, or legacy ASMX? SOAP, or REST?

Comment: @John: ASMX webservices

Comment: Using ASMX makes it much harder. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: hmm.. well I think using token based authentication for my services might solve my problem but I am not sure how to proceed!

Comment: That's my point. There are few choices with ASMX. You'll have to create a [SOAP Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx)